# How to automatically run many video in sequence with php

Tags: php, video-streaming

I am trying to run many videos 1 by 1 in sequence or random
and my code is like this below

```
<div class="fullscreen-bg">
 <video loop muted autoplay poster="assets/img/poster.png" class="fullscreen-bg__video">
    <source src="assets/clip/clip<?php echo(rand(4,5,6)); ?>.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 </video>
</div>
```

and it's just playing random only 1 video and after that, it's stopped.I want to do is keep playing other videos without stopping.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17521012/html5-video-loop-src-change-on-end-play-function-not-working

Answer (score 0):

I hope it's help full for you  I Get reference from [PHP: load one of 3 html snippets randomly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27444117/php-load-one-of-3-html-snippets-randomly/27444136)

PHP:

```
$videos = array('cloud', 'bath', 'train');
$i = rand(0, count($videos) - 1); // between 0 and $videos count minus 1
```

HTML:

```
<video loop autoplay class="StretchtoFit">
 <source src="assets/videos/<?= $videos[$i]; ?>.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 <source src="assets/videos/<?= $videos[$i]; ?>.ogg" type="video/ogg">
 <source src="assets/videos/<?= $videos[$i]; ?>.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```